# The rerangements by choose $n$ numbers from $1$ to $m$ ($m\geq n)$

Tags: combinations

After I learned the Error permutation problems, I start to think the more complicated situations. Choose $n$ different numbers
from number $1$ to $m$ ($m≥n$) to make a permutation,what's the sums of permutations that all *i-th*  $(0<i≤n)$ position numbers is not number $i$?
For example,when $n=2$ and $m=3$,there are only three situations.

$$2 1$$
$$2 3$$
$$3 1$$
I want a function like ***Γ(n + 1, -1)/e*** when $n=m$.

Answer (score 1):

Inclusion-exclusion is your friend.

Let $A$ be the set of permutationss of $n$ elements from $1,\dots,m.$ Let $A_i$ be the set of such permutations with $i$th element $i.$

Then you get:$$\left|A\setminus (A_1\cup A_n)\right|=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\binom nk \frac{(m-k)!}{(m-n)!}$$

When $n=m$ this gives the usual derangements term:

$$\binom{n}k\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-n)!}=\frac{m!}{k!}$$

When $n=m-1,$

$$\binom{n}k\frac{(m-k)!}{(m-n)!}=\frac{(m-k)(m-1)!}{k!}$$

When $n=2,m=3$ you get:

$$6-4+1=3.$$

Comment: Thank you sir,but can it be simplified with $n,m$ and gamma function?Sorry for my additional requirement because it is hard to make a program to calculate now.@Thomas Andrews